# Can every Gaussian integral be reduced to elementary functions and poly-logarithms only?

Tags: integration, special-functions, gaussian-integral, polylogarithm

Let us  define a following function:
\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathcal J}^{(d)}(\vec{A}) := \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-u^2} \prod\limits_{\xi=1}^d erf(A_\xi u) du
\end{eqnarray}
for $\vec{A}:=\left(A_\xi\right)_{\xi=1}^d \in {\mathbb R}_+^d$. This function is analyzed in [An integral involving error functions and a Gaussian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358738/an-integral-involving-error-functions-and-a-gaussian?noredirect=1&lq=1) .

Now let $A_5 \ge 0$ be real and let us consider a a following definite integral:
\begin{equation}
I(A_5):= \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-u^2} [erf(u)]^4 erf[A_5 u] du = {\mathcal J}^{(5)}\left(1,1,1,1,A_5\right)
\end{equation}

Now, by differentiating with respect to the parameter $A_5$ and then by integrating the result back again with respect to that parameter we obtained the following results:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&I(A_5)=
 \frac{8}{\pi}\arctan(\frac{A_5}{\sqrt{2+A_5^2}}) {\mathcal J}^{(3)}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+A_5^2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+A_5^2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+A_5^2}}\right) -\\
&& \frac{96}{\pi^{5/2}} \int\limits_0^{A_5} \frac{t \sqrt{\frac{t^2+4}{t^2+2}} }{t^4+7 t^2+12} \arctan\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+2}}\right) \arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+4}}\right) dt
\end{eqnarray}

```
A5 = RandomReal[{0, 5}, WorkingPrecision -> 50];
NIntegrate[Exp[-u^2] Erf[u]^4 Erf[A5 u], {u, 0, Infinity}]
8/Pi NIntegrate[
  1/(1 + t^2) 1/Sqrt[2 + t^2] J30[1/Sqrt[2 + t^2], 1/Sqrt[2 + t^2], 
    1/Sqrt[2 + t^2]], {t, 0, A5}]
8/Pi (ArcTan[A5/Sqrt[2 + A5^2]] J30[1/Sqrt[2 + A5^2], 
     1/Sqrt[2 + A5^2], 1/Sqrt[2 + A5^2]] + 
   12/Pi^(3/2) NIntegrate[( 
      t Sqrt[(4 + t^2)/(2 + t^2)])/ (12 + 7 t^2 + t^4) ArcTan[t/Sqrt[
       2 + t^2]] ArcTan[1/Sqrt[4 + t^2] ], {t, 0, A5}])
```

[image]

The message that I want to pass on is that we were not able to express the quantity  $I(A_5)$ through elementary functions and di-logarithms only but instead we end up with an additional term that involves integrating a product of arc tangent function and a function containing square roots. My question is how do we deal with that last term? Is it possible to express the quantity in question through poly-logarithms ?

Note that integrals involving arc tangents and square roots were already analyzed in [How do I evaluate this integral :$\int \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1-x^2} } \arctan( \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2})dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359461/how-do-i-evaluate-this-integral-int-frac1-sqrt1-x2-arctan-frac?rq=1) and in [How find this integral $\int\frac{\sqrt{x-1}\arctan{(x\sqrt{x-1})}}{x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589407/how-find-this-integral-int-frac-sqrtx-1-arctanx-sqrtx-1xdx?rq=1) . However my example does not seem to be possible to be tackled by methods being used in those other questions.

Update: It is likely that the integral in question can be tackled by using integration by parts. Indeed the following identities hold true:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int\limits_0^{A_5} \frac{t \sqrt{\frac{t^2+4}{t^2+2}} }{t^4+7 t^2+12} \arctan\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+2}}\right)dt=\arctan\left(\frac{A_5}{\sqrt{A_5^2+2}}\right) \arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{A_5^2+2}{A_5^2+4}}\right)+\\
&&
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8}
\sum\limits_{\xi\in\{-1,1\}}
\sum\limits_{\xi_1\in\{-1,1\}}
\sum\limits_{\eta\in\{-1,1\}}
\sum\limits_{\eta_1\in\{-1,1\}}
\xi \eta_1 (-\sqrt{3}+\xi_1) \sqrt{2+\xi_1 \sqrt{3}}\cdot
{\mathfrak F}^{(1,\frac{-\imath A_5 + \sqrt{4+A_5^2}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2+A_5^2}})}_{\frac{\imath}{\sqrt{2}(\xi+\eta \sqrt{3})},-\xi_1 \eta_1 \sqrt{2-\xi_1 \sqrt{3}}}\\
&&\int\limits_0^{A_5} \frac{t \sqrt{\frac{t^2+4}{t^2+2}} }{t^4+7 t^2+12} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+4}}\right)dt=\left.\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+4}}\right) \arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{t^2+2}{t^2+4}}\right)\right|_{t=0}^{t=A_5}+\\
&&
\frac{1}{4}
\sum\limits_{\xi\in\{-1,1\}}
\sum\limits_{\xi_1\in\{-1,1\}}
\sum\limits_{\eta\in\{-1,1\}}
\sum\limits_{\eta_1\in\{-1,1\}}
\xi \xi_1 \eta_1 {\mathfrak F}^{(\sqrt{2}-1,\frac{-\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{4+A_5^2}}{\sqrt{2+A_5^2}})}_{\imath(\xi+\eta \sqrt{2}),\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \imath \xi_1 \sqrt{1+\xi_1 \eta_1 2 \imath \sqrt{2}}}
\end{eqnarray}
where the function ${\mathfrak F}^{(A,B)}_{a,b}$ is related to di-logarithms and is defined in [An integral involving error functions and a Gaussian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358738/an-integral-involving-error-functions-and-a-gaussian?noredirect=1&lq=1) .